# Omission of articles before countable nouns

Tags: articles, countable-nouns

> It may be winter, dark and cold, but the village of Taft will be in
>   **festive mood** on December 18th.” “Ladies and Gentlemen, according to **long-standing tradition**…

From English collocations in use (Advanced) by Felicity O’Dell, P50;U23.

“Long standing tradition” and “festive mood” are countable nouns; however, in these examples, they are used without articles. Could someone please explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with *tradition*. It can be both countable and uncountable. According to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tradition), it is uncountable when it has the following meaning:

> very old customs, beliefs, or stories, **considered together**

Here are a few examples from different dictionaries:

> According to family tradition, Mr Thomas was a teacher.
>
> By tradition, it’s the bride’s parents who pay for the wedding.
>
> The move represents a break with tradition.

As for *mood*, the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/mood) says it can be considered both countable and uncountable, too. I agree that the indefinite article is usually expected before a singular indefinite *mood*. And according to other dictionaries I have used (Collins and Longman), *mood* is always countable. Anyway, if we say "in a festive mood", it's certainly OK. Let's attribute the lack of *a* before *mood* in your example to that rare point of view the Cambridge dictionary has noted (unless someone can give a better explanation).